# Accessing element of a complex javascript object

Tags: javascript

Please refer to
https://jsfiddle.net/qL35dvsm/

I have

```
var data = {"name": [{"message": "Please enter your name", "code": "required"}]};

for (d in data)
{
    // name
    alert(d[0].message);
}
```

I want to access "Please enter your name" but I get 'undefined'.

Comment: In this specific case it would be `data.name[0].message`.

Comment: i want to access it by for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using

```
data.name[0].message
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
var data = {"name": [{"message": "Please enter your name", "code": "required"}]};

for (d in data)
{
    // name
    alert(data[d][0].message);
}
```